# IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, encryption, des

I have the below method:

```
public String decrypt(String strToBeDecrypted) {
    try {
        strToBeDecrypted = URLDecoder.decode(strToBeDecrypted, "UTF-8");
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey skey = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);

        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, ivSpec);

        byte[] keyByteArray = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(strToBeDecrypted);

        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(keyByteArray);

        return new String(original, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(ExceptionUtil.getDetailedMessage(e));
    }
    return "";
}
```

This is throwing

```
"name=javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;message=Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher;"
```

at the below line:

```
 byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(keyByteArray);
```

Can someone please tell me whats the problem here?

Comment: Tried to print out `keyByteArray.length`? Is it multiple of 8?

Comment: Can you post your encryption code too? Perhaps create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that triggers your exception.

Comment: Side note: if you have any choice in the matter, don't use DES - it's far too weak. Consider Triple DES or, preferably, AES.

Answer (score 4):

The input length it's referring to is the length of your ciphertext (strToBeDecrypted), which it expects to be a multiple of the block size. It is implied that by default the library is expecting your input to be padded.

That means either you either need to set the padding to 'none' when decrypting (as that was the 'padding' used when encrypting) or you've corrupted the ciphertext somehow.

Try changing "DES" to "DES/ECB/NoPadding". I don't know what the default cipher mode is for your implementation, but it's typically "ECB" or "CBC". If neither of those two work then you're corrupting your ciphertext somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this. It works for me.

```
public String decrypt(String message) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("HG58YZ3CR9"
            .getBytes("utf-8"));
    final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
        keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    final byte[] encData = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(message);
    final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(encData);

    return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");
}
```